# Tranferring Texmaker settings from Windows to Linux

Tags: windows, texmaker, linux

In principle, this could turn out to be a *very* stupid question. But, let me ask this right away: I am very happy with Windows that I am planning to shift to a Linux distribution later today. So, my beloved editor is Texmaker (no sarcasm intended, as it will soon become obvious). I have added a lot of custom completions to Texmaker.

Is there anyway I can carry these things over to the Linux distribution?

**Source**:  Windows 7

**Target**: A Linux Distribution

I'd be more specific about the distribution, if that is needed. Please feel free to ask me other relevant things in this regard.

Comment: Isn't TeXmaker a cross-platform editor?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It indeed is. I am an absolute beginner. So, this question can turn out be completely stupid, or might reflect my ignorance... :)

Comment: Can't you copy your `.ini` file setting?

Comment: @azetina I am not sure... I have not shifted yet. So, I'd like to know what I'd do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to transfer your auto completions to another system. If Linux reads `.ini` files then simply go to (see image below)

> Options->Settings File->Save a copy of the settings file

[image]

Now under Linux Texmaker, do the same thing but with `Replace the settings file by a new one` which is still found under `Options`.

This would be the most logical thing to do.

Comment: Any idea where this is actually stored?

Comment: @ForkrulAssail somewhere here `$HOME/.config/xm1/texmaker.ini` on Linux and on windows in user profile folders may be