# remember user shortcut in texmaker on usb key

Tags: portability

I would like to know if there is a way to remember all the configuration (user shortcut,...) made on texmaker. My problem is that my faculty has Latex and Texmaker installed on the computers but the shortcut aren't remembered when i close the session .

I was thinking of installing a portable version of texmaker but i am under impression that it is really slow (slower than with the native version)

Comment: Why don't you just ask your faculty what is up with their installation? Perhaps they don't store user app data? Where exactly is the user short cut you made saved?

Comment: you can see here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76252/tranferring-texmaker-settings-from-windows-to-linux