# Is there a way to export user tags?

Tags: texmaker

Just wondering since I have to change computers soon, if there is a way to export textmaker settings such as user tags. I had a look in the program files for a settings folder but couldnt find one.

thanks

Comment: What is your operating system and version of [texmaker](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index.html) (not textmaker)? As far as I can tell, nothing is said about this in the [documentation](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html), but [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76252/34551) should be useful.

Comment: Looks like user tags are one of the things included in the settings file, so the question Clement mentions should provide a solution.